# How to setup template? in xcode

Tags: xcode, python, templates

How can I make it so in xcode when I create a blank file, text is already written? For example, at the the top of a new file:

```
#Project Name
#User name
#Date
#Build


#Setup Globals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very complete tutorial on Bob McCune [website](http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/). I have used it myself and it works great.